# Objects are slippery - how to increase the friction

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to put a pile of books in my scene. Since I want the books to lay in a realistic way, I'm using physics to let them laydown in an automatic way.

When I animate the books, they have a strange slippery behaviour (see video). How can I add a lot more friction to the objects? Also there is a strange "explosion" when objects collide (like they intersect and this generates a strong tension and repulsion).

Here's the source file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6vqddjMB

[image]

Comment: the problem was that I parented 2 different meshes.. I join the meshes and now the friction is not there anymore.